# JUnit Test for when clause in Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, junit

How to write test case for below piece of code:

```kotlin
fun calculateResult(score: Int): String {
    return when {
        score >= 257 -> "Genius"
        score in 234..256 -> "Great"
        else -> "Good"
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you think could a test case look like? Which result would you expect for an input of `258`? Or `233`? Or `248`?

Comment: Input(258) -> Output("Genius"), Input(233) -> Output("Good"), Input(248)->Output("Great")

Answer (score 2):

As you would test a method with many if statements. You have to write a test for every each possible return value.
You call the method and give it a score and then you make an assertion.

**Example:**

```
@Test
fun test() {
   
    val test = calculateResult(258)
    
    Assertions.assertThat(test).isEqualTo("Genius")
}
```

Comment: That means I have to write 3 test cases, correct?

Comment: how to test `score in 234..256 -> "Great"`

Comment: yes. so many that you think you've got every possible case covered

Comment: you write one test per number. For the range I would pick a few numbers between 234 and 256 and test the method with them.